# How does gcc determine if to generate a 32-bit or 64-bit executable file by default?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, solaris

In my 64-bit Solaris, my gcc by default will generate 32-bit executable file (for generating 64-bit executable file, need add "-m64" compile option) by default. While in my 64-bit Linux, my gcc will generate 64-bit executable file by default. I try to find the cause in [gcc website](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html), but unfortunately, there are so many related options (--with-arch, --with-cpu, --with-abi, etc). From the document, I can't see which can determine generating 32-bit or 64-bit executable file.

Could anyone give some advices on this issue?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how the compiler is installed, which really comes down to the distribution and possibly install options.  If there is any doubt and need for certainty, simply include the -m option; it does not hurt to use -m32 when 32-bit is the default, and likewise for -m64 when 64-bit is the default.

Comment: Which install options?

Comment: That is very distribution-specific. What are you trying to accomplish?  Just automatically detect the default?

Comment: Try 'gcc -dumpspecs' to see if that gives the desired information.

Comment: Also, 'gcc -v' on a simple source file may help.

Comment: Hmm, re-reading the original question, maybe I misunderstood; are you just looking to understand how to choose 32-bit versus 64-bit when compiling?  If so, -m32 and -m64.

Comment: Sorry, my question is why gcc generate 32-bit executable in 64-bit Solaris versus 64-bit executable in 64-bit Linux? I think for both 64-bit OSs, the gccs should have a unified behavior: generating 64-bit or 32-bit executable files. What options determine the gcc behaviors?

Comment: That logic makes sense.  However, how GCC operates on each platform is a distribution-specific matter, and may even be more complicated in that it could depend on system configuration and even user configuration.  I agree 32-bit execs by default in Solaris seems odd.  If it seems wrong to you, try locating the gcc ('whence gcc', or 'type gcc' should do the trick) and see if there are hints from that (perhaps it is a path issue).

Comment: @NanXiao - because the gcc maintainers have decided to choose different defaults for different platforms.  https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58833 covers their thinking about what the Solaris default should be.

Comment: @alanc - I actually do not believe it's as much the gcc maintainers as the distribution maintainers in this case; I built a distribution, and the choice was mine.

Comment: Run `gcc -v` without any other arguments. The output will show you the default for your particular installation of `gcc`

Answer (score 1):

When you compile gcc, you use the --target option to specify the appropriate system you want to generate the compiler for. For knowing what all targets GCC supports, you can either check gcc/configure file or oogle through the gcc/config/ folder. Once you generate the compiler, the "compile" command, i.e., gcc source.c -o object.o will always generate object for the default target you have compiled gcc for.

However, you may be able to generate objects for various variations around the specified target. E.g. you may be able to generate both 32-bit and 64-bit binaries for 64-bit systems.

As an example, configure --target=mips64-elf will generate the gcc compiler for the 64-bit mips target. Once the compiler is generated, whenever you type in gcc -c source.c -o object.o, a 64-bit mips object file will be generated.

So if you type in gcc -v on both of your systems in question, you will see how the gcc was configured to begin with, and that should answer your concern.

Comment: configure won't change the default behavior of gcc, it will setup the makefile to use appropriate gcc options. Any `gcc -c source.c -o object.o` you type manually will still use the default options.

Comment: The gcc makefile doesn't use gcc -- it uses the system compiler to build gcc (which might be some other version of gcc, or might be some other compiler).  When you run configure to build gcc, you specify what the default target for the gcc you're building should be.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Unless you `configure` GCC with `--disable-bootstrap` or if your GCC is a cross compiler, a default GCC straight compiler is compiled in several stages, so that the installed binary is indeed compiled by "itself" (the *same* GCC, actually in some previous stage)

Comment: @pqnet, Agree, configure will not change the behavior of your installed gcc. What I meant to say is that once the compiler is built, the target and the default options are fixed. You may be able to vary some options still around the target (like m32 and m64, abi etc)

Answer (score 0):

At the [document](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html) you referred, please grep for "enable-targets" option.